# Webdriver xpath ranking

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I can't figure out how to select the choice "2" for the following html code:

```
<div class="formRow">
<div>
<label for="A100000000003201292">Q6~!@$%^a59;*()Q6</label><br>
<div class="ranking">
1<br>
<input type="radio" name="A100000000003201292" id="A100000000003201292" class="frb" value="100000000009634067">
</div>
<div class="ranking">
2<br>
<input type="radio" name="A100000000003201292" id="A100000000003201292" class="frb" value="100000000009634068">
</div>
<div class="ranking">
3<br>
<input type="radio" name="A100000000003201292" id="A100000000003201292" class="frb" value="100000000009634069">
</div>
<div class="ranking">
4<br>
<input type="radio" name="A100000000003201292" id="A100000000003201292" class="frb" value="100000000009634070">
</div>
<div class="ranking">
5<br>
<input type="radio" name="A100000000003201292" id="A100000000003201292" class="frb" value="100000000009634071">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I've used the follow code to select the correct "ranking" web element.

```
                WebElement rankingButton = questionElement.findElement
(By.xpath("//div[@class='ranking'and contains(.,'" + answers.get(0) + "') ]"));
```

where questionElement is a webElement pointing to the formRow div and answer.get(0) is equal to 2.

This code succeeds, but any attempt to try and retrieve the input element in order to click the radio button fails to find the element. I have tried the following:

```
//1.
                rankingButton = rankingButton.findElement
(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio'"));

//2.
rankingButton = rankingButton.findElement
    (By.xpath("//input[@class='frb'"));
```

Comment: missing closing square-bracket : `//input[@type='radio'`, is that a typo? How about using this XPath : `.//input[@type='radio']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath will find you the input button with the text '2'

```
//div[contains(text(), '2')]/input[@type='radio']
```